# App returns 404 on startup

Tags: python, flask

I created a Flask application with the following structure:

```
/nhs-listpull
/listpull
    /static
    /templates
    __init__.py
    models.py
    views.py
app.db
config.py
run.py
```

run.py

```
from listpull import app
app.run(debug=True)
```

/listpull/__init__.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from mom.client import SQLClient
from smartfocus.restclient import RESTClient

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
...
```

/listpull/views.py

```
import logging
import time
from flask import request, render_template, flash, redirect, send_file
from zlib import compress, decompress
from StringIO import StringIO


@app.route('/')
def index():
    ... do stuff ...
    return render_template('jobs.html', jobs=jobs)
```

When I run `./run.py` the web server starts up, but browsing returns 404.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

`listpull/views.py` is never imported, so no routes will be registered. You need to import it in your `__init__.py` file (be careful with circular imports):

```
...

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

...

import listpull.views
```

Comment: ok, so now in /listpull/views.py I get "NameError: name 'app' is not defined" for @app.route('/')

Comment: @MarkRichman: You have to import it: `from listpull import app`.

Comment: Why not `from . import app` ?

Comment: Import app in your views.py file.